# grep last match and it's following lines

Tags: grep, match

I've learnt how to `grep` lines before and after the match and to `grep` the last match but I haven't discovered how to `grep` the last match and the lines underneath it.

The scenario is a server log.
I want to list a dynamic output from a command. The command is likely to be used several times in one server log. So I imagine the match would be the command and somehow `grep` can use `-A`  with some other flag or variation of a tail command, to complete the outcome I'm seeking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The approach I would take it to reverse the problem as it's easier to find the first match and print the context lines. Take the file:

```
$ cat file
foo
1
2
foo
3
4
foo
5
6
```

Say we want the last match of `foo` and the following to `lines` we could just reverse the file with `tac`, find the first match and `n` lines above using `-Bn` and stop using `-m1`. Then simple re-reverse the output with tac:

```
$ tac file | grep foo -B2 -m1 | tac
foo
5
6
```

Tools like `tac` and `rev` can make problems that seem difficult much easier.

Answer (score 1):

using awk instead:

```
awk '/pattern/{m=$0;l=NR}l+1==NR{n=$0}END{print m;print n}' foo.log
```

small test, find the last line matching `/8/` and the next line of it:

```
kent$  seq 20|awk '/8/{m=$0;l=NR}l+1==NR{n=$0}END{print m;print n}'
18
19
```